# Is it true that anything that can be coded in one programming language can be done in any other language?

Tags: programming-languages

Is it true that anything that can be coded in one programming language can be done in any other language?
For instance, is it possible to code an Android App in c or c++ instead of Java?

Comment: What do you mean by anything? Any algorithm?

Comment: Take a look at : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness. Yes it's true, as long as the languages are turing-complete. It might be really long to do something in a language, but really fast in another.

Comment: @Simimmo Yes, any algorithm!

Comment: @MaximePeloquin Thanks, that makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,the only difference being, some languages give inbuilt libraries for certain implementations while in others, you may have to implement it by yourself.
Take for example: consider A and B to be matrices, In Octave you can multiply them by just doing A*B, while in other languages, like C, you should write the full code yourself.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127735/android-development-using-c-and-c have a look at this

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course no doubt. The only thing is that somethings can be done easily in one programming language while in other it may be a tough one.

Answer (score 0):

This is my personal opinion; it is difficult to answer with 100% accuracy because I do not know the ins and outs of every language that exists but I will try to answer in two parts.

Short answer:
Yes; it is entirely possible to do anything in one language in another language. However, it may be harder to duplicate specific logic across languages.

Long answer:
Although it can be possible to implement the same program/class/software in one language in another language, this is not always the best thing to do.
For example, some languages have advantages over others in specific areas. FORTRAN, C, and C++ are all languages that can produce fast results for math operations when compared to languages like Java or C#. But C# for example, gives you much more flexibility than say C++ with object orientation.

So for example, you have millions of operations that need to be done, and time is important to you - C/C++ would be a better language to implement compared to C#.

But If you cared less about the efficiency, and wanted to leverage the benefits of OOD within C#, then you would use C#.

Note:
I tried to be simple with this example, remember a book could be written on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

A programming language can do anything another can, but certain steps are put in place so they can not. You don't want Javascript calling to your windowAPI and bringing up windows outside your browser, or placing bat files on your computer without your permision